# Material UI CDN example is not working require is not defined

Tags: material-ui

Material UI CDN example is not working which is provided in github. Below is for the same .
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/cdn/index.html

It is giving an error that "require is not defined" from material UI CDN . Yesterday it was working . Today it is not working . Looks like material UI CDN is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link:
if you are using react+material-ui

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js

THERE ARE TWO WAYS:

1. if you are using require function in your js then remove it as it is server side function not client side.
2. Else you can use require.js cdn link (mentioned above) in your client side before your script.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but i am not calling require any where in the script . But it is getting called in material ui script file only (material-ui.development.js). i have tried adding script  require.min.js also even though it is not working .

Comment: I have shared one github URL in post . Can you please check that url . It has code